# An homepage in a div, not working with IE

Tags: jquery, css, html

H_i

I want to show an homepage in a div-tag. Here is an small code, that works in browsers Firefox, Chrome, Opera, but in Internet Explorer it does not work. Have anybody hints?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/myproj/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: lightsalmon;
            }
            .inner_homepage_div {
                position: fixed;
                top : 100px;
                left : 0px;
                width: 100%;
                z-index:10;
            }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function fHeight() {
                    $('#inner_page').height($(window).height()-125);
                    $('#hpage').css({
                        'width': '100%',
                        'height': '100%'
                    });
                }
                $('#inner_page').html('<object id="hpage" data="http://www.ee" />');
                fHeight();
                fHeight();
                $(window).resize(fHeight);
            });//
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <div id="inner_page" class="inner_homepage_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: What type of resource is the `<object>` tag embedding?

Comment: An universal solution i need, that works in all version of IE-s.

Comment: @user1929552 I understand you want a universal solution for all IE's but each one acts a little differently. What version are you specifically testing in?

Comment: @user1929552 I know you don't have to with `HTML5` but for older browser compatibility sake, you may want to specify `<style type="text/css">`.

Comment: is you **$(window).resize(fHeight);** supposed to be IN the **'$(document).ready(function() {'** function ??

Comment: Also, take a look at your IE security settings. Cross site scripting withing an object, it might be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

So we know,  what is http://www.ee ?  It's missing.. Bits
Are you actually getting anything?  If so what?  ( would post as a comment but stack likes to make you have 50 rep )

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the best compatibility with IE, you can use the script from http://modernizr.com/ or / and for HTML5 elements the HTML5-trunk:

```
<!--[if IE]>
     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

But if I just see your code, the problem probably causes due to the 100% width and 100% height at the same time, elder browsers did not support this. Furthermore, why do you insert your jQuery snippet like a jQuery-Plugin? Simply use:

```
     $(function() {
        function fHeight() {
            $('#inner_page').height($(window).height()-125);
            $('#hpage').css({
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%'
            });
        }
        $('#inner_page').html('<object id="hpage" data="http://www.ee" />');
        fHeight();
        // fHeight(); -> why the second time???
        $(window).resize(fHeight);
    });
```